# 'RPC Server is unavailable' error but script still appears to work

Tags: powershell

```
$computer = get-content C:\test\DNS_Server_Name.csv
$NICs = Get-WMIObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -computername $computer |where{$_.IPEnabled -eq “TRUE”}
  Foreach($NIC in $NICs) {

$DNSServers = “198.102.234.125",”198.102.234.126"
 $NIC.SetDNSServerSearchOrder($DNSServers)
 $NIC.SetDynamicDNSRegistration(“TRUE”)
}
```

Getting error "RPC Server is unavailable". However, the script still inputs the DNS server as needed. I ran this with only one server name in the csv file. Any idea why I'm getting this error even though it still seems to work?

Comment: Break down your script. Run each line independently. Check the output. We cannot debug it for you.

Comment: Have you tried running this in debugging mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script still runs because the `Get-WMIObject` cmdlet is not terminating, check this article to [understand Non-Terminating Errors in PowerShell](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/understanding-non-terminating-errors-in-powershell/)

If you want to stop the script when `Get-WMIObject` generates an error, just add `–ErrorAction Stop`

```
$NICs = Get-WMIObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -computername $computer –ErrorAction Stop | where {$_.IPEnabled -eq “TRUE”}
```

If you want further informations about the error "RPC Server is unavailable" itself, you may want to check that the "Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI-In)" rule is enabled in the firewall for each remote machine, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11338395/3759822).